# How to print the average, min and max for a specific year from a CSV file?

Tags: python, excel, csv, average, min

I need help with this exercise. I have a csv file like this one in one column but with 16000 entries:

Entity,Code,Year,Life expectancy (years)
Afghanistan,AFG,1950,27.638
Afghanistan,AFG,1951,27.878
Serbia,SRB,1995,71.841
Zimbabwe,ZWE,2019,61.49

I need to print this, I got the first 2 parts working.

1. ✅What is the year and country that has the lowest life expectancy in the dataset?
2. ✅What is the year and country that has the highest life expectancy in the dataset?
3. ❌Allow the user to type in a year, then, find the average life expectancy for that year. Then find the country with the minimum and the one with the maximum life expectancy for that year.

So far I´m here and I need some help on how to get the last part to print something like this related to the year input by the user:

**For the year 1959:**

**The average life expectancy across all countries was 54.95**

**The max life expectancy was in Norway with 73.49**

**The min life expectancy was in Mali with 28.077**

```
import csv
print ("Enter a year to find the average life expectancy for that year: ")
input_year = input ("\n""YEAR: ")


#Allow the user to type in a year, then, find the average life expectancy for that year
def subset_year(all_data, selected_year):
    year_only = []
    for entity, code, year, expectancy in all_data:
        if year == selected_year:
            year_only.append((entity, code, year, expectancy))
    return year_only

def pr_row(headers, row):
    return ", ".join(f"{label}:{value}" for label, value in zip(headers, row))

data = []
with open(r"C:\Users\X230\Desktop\Python class\life-expectancy.csv") as database:
    reader = csv.reader(database)
    # the first row in the CSV file is; Entity,Code,Year,Life expectancy (years)
    # example of the data in the CVS file: Afghanistan,AFG,1950,27.638
    parts = next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        # print(line) #this prints everything, not very useful so I removed it
        # Save the parts I need into variables
        entity, code, year, expectancy = line
        data.append([entity, code, int(year), float(expectancy)])

def key_year(row):
    return row[3]
print()
print("The overall max life expectancy is: ", pr_row(parts, max(data, key=key_year)))
print("The overall min life expectancy is: ", pr_row(parts, min(data, key=key_year)))
print("The average life expectancy across all countries was: ", ) #??????????????
print("The max life expectancy was in: ", ) #????????????????????????????????????
print("The min life expectancy was in: ", ) #????????????????????????????????????
year = input_year
all_by_year = subset_year(data, year)
print(all_by_year)
```

Comment: can you use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this? this would be much easier with `df = pd.read_csv(filepath); df.groupby("Year")["Life expectancy (years)"].mean()`, and similarly for [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html)

Comment: How did you solve the first 2 points? 
The third point is basically the same with just a small difference that you use a subset of the original dataset based on the user input. Also consider how an average is calculated.   As you wrote the code to solve the first 2 points, these hints should get you started. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is iterate over the lines of the file and separate the rows that are useful. Then, I would use the `map()` function to get the *life expectancy* of each row (without having to use a `for` loop to iterate over each one of them), and by putting that into `min()` and `max()` functions you can easily get the minimum and maximum value.

For the average, I just used `sum()` to get the sum of all selected values and divided that by the length of a list containing all those values (basically, the number of values). You can use `mean()` to get the average too, but you would need to import the `statistics` module first.

Finally, it iterates over the selected rows until it finds the row which contains the minimum/maximum values, just to print it along with the country of that row.

```
import csv

year_input = input('Enter the year: ')

with open('data.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    lines = []
    
    # We iterate over the lines in the file, excluding the header of course.
    # If the year matches the user input, then we append that row to a list.
    
    for line in reader:
        if line == ['Entity', 'Code', 'Year', 'Life expectancy (years)']:
            pass
        else:
            if line[2] == year_input:
                lines.append(line)
                
    # Once we have that list, we get the average, the minimum and the maximum value for the life expectancy.

    average = sum(map(lambda x: float(x[3]), lines))/len(list(map(lambda x: x[3], lines)))
    minimum = min(map(lambda x: x[3], lines))
    maximum = max(map(lambda x: x[3], lines))
    
    print('For the year ' + year_input + ':')
    print('The average life expectancy across all countries was ' + str(average))
    
    # Now, we iterate over the rows we selected before until we find the minimum and maximum value.
    # When we find the row with the minimum/maximum value, we print it next to the country on that same row.
    
    for line in lines:
        if line[3] == minimum:
            print('The min life expectancy was in ' + line[0] + ' with ' + line[3])
        if line[3] == maximum:
            print('The max life expectancy was in ' + line[0] + ' with ' + line[3])
```